# Is the map taking a matrix to its semisimple part algebraic (or at least holomorphic)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, cv.complex-variables

Let $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the set of $n \times n$ complex matrices.  Let $\sigma\colon \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the map that takes a matrix to its semisimple part.  In more detail, consider $M \in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$.  Let $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ be the generalized eigenspaces of $M$, and for $1 \leq i \leq k$ let $\lambda_i$ be the generalized eigenvalue associated to $V_i$.  Thus $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $M$, the subspace $V_i$ is the kernel of $(M - \lambda_i)^n$, and $\mathbb{C}^n$ is the direct sum of the $V_i$.  The image $\sigma(M)$ is then the matrix whose associated linear map scales each $V_i$ by $\lambda_i$.

Question: Is $\sigma$ an algebraic map?  Or at least holomorphic?

If I had seen this question a few days ago, my impulse would be that the answer has to be "yes".  However, as a byproduct of a proof of an unrelated fact, I have what looks like a very indirect proof that the answer is "no".  I'm asking for a direct proof as a kind of "idiot test" to see if my reasoning is flawed.

Actually, it looks like a bit of a pain to even see that $\sigma$ is continuous, though surely that must be true!

Comment: If I understand your description correctly, then $\sigma$ is the identity on diagonalizable matrices with no multiple eigenvalues. These are dense, so $\sigma$ is not continuous.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Oh, good point!  That pretty much kills the question.  I'll delete it (after waiting a while to make sure you can see my thanks!).

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like I can delete it, so I suppose it stays!

Comment: Another way of seeing @ChristianRemling's point:  the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} \varepsilon & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ are semisimple for $\varepsilon \ne 0$, but nilpotent for $\varepsilon = 0$.  I remember that, despite the simplicity (no pun intended) of this example, I (like you) was so convinced that $\sigma$ must be continuous that I spent some time trying to find a mistake in it.

Comment: @LSpice: Cool, thanks!  That's an enlightening example.